# adding www. from http:// in codeigniter tried code

Tags: codeigniter

I have a domain name: http://dulaboratories.com want to change the http:// to http://www

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.info$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dulaboratories\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dulaboratories.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```